# how to read array in another method/class

Tags: java, android, arrays

im new to android. im quite familiar with objective c.
As you can see i have a arraylist that is loaded from a csv file.
I cant seam to figure it out why i cant read the array list in my "public void buttonClicked(View v)" for this line "for (String str : list) ..."

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findButton);
    //searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mainSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.titleCategory1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

        InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("Category.csv"));

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);
        Log.d("test", "reading csv");

        String [] nextLine;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            list.add(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1]+ nextLine[2]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void buttonClicked(View v){

    Log.d("test", "button clicked");
    strFind2 = mainSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    /*
    for (String str : list) {
            if (str.contains(strFind2)) {

                Log.d("test", "contains easy");

            } else {

                Log.d("test", "dont contains easy");

            }*/

    }

}
```

can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your code, I guess you are accessing list within same Activity.

So just declare,

```
List<String> list;
```

**As a class level member field**,

And access in `buttonClicked(View v)`

```
private List<String> list
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findButton);
    //searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.titleCategory1);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also I am suggesting you to please read basic Java programming tutorials about class and scope of variables and methods.